# .toUpperCase with one element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why it is not working with ELEMENT of an array, not of all array.
It is nested loop

```
for (var q = 0; q < array.length; q++) { 
  arraySymb[k] = array[q].toUpperCase() ;
  break;        
}
```

**console:** 
`Uncaught TypeError: array[q].toUpperCase is not a function`

Comment: So what is array[q] ? Clearly it is not something that has a toUpperCase method/

Comment: Seems like you're missing some of your code. Also, what data type is in your array? If you have array of strings it'll work.

Comment: remove "break;" your loop will only cycle once i'm pretty sure :/

Comment: also, make sure your array elements are strings (i.e. `array[q].toString().toUpperCase()`)

Comment: `toUpperCase` will work only with data of type `String`. You need to convert the array entry to String if you really need this. `array[q].toString().toUpperCase();`

Comment: `array[q]` is _not_ a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to convert an array to all uppercase. Conveniently, Javascript has the `Array.prototype.map` method.

What you are trying to do could be done with

```
arraySymb = array.map(str=>str.toUpperCase())
```

With that aside, obviously the issue you are having is that an element of an array is not a string, since toUpperCase is a method only strings have. You can check your array by looping through it. To identify the offending element you can use this:

```
array.forEach((e, i)=>{
   if (typeof e !== 'string')
      console.log(e, "is not a string at index=", i)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your array elements are strings.

`array[q].toString().toUpperCase()`

Also, doesn't break end the loop?!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is a string first

```
for (let q = 0; q < array.length; q++) { 

  if (typeof array[q] === 'string'){
     arraySymb[k] = array[q].toUpperCase() ;
     break;        
   }
  else{
    debugger; // to examine the value
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one aspect that has been overlooked is that the error message cites an uncaught TypeError, meaning that if the code were to catch it, then some code might still execute until an Exception were to occur, as follows:

```js
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;
var myData = d.g("myData");

var arr = ["1", "ana", "2", "bill", true, "cathy"];
var arrStr = [];
try {
  for (var i = 0, k = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i += 1, k += 1) {
    arrStr[k] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
    myData.innerHTML += arrStr[k] + "\t";
  }

} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
  }
  arr.forEach(function(el, i, arr) {
    if (typeof el !== 'string') {
      console.log("***" + arr[i] + "*** is not a string at index=", i, " in arr ", arr);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#myData {
  background: #eef;
  color: #f03;
  font-size: 120%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="myData"></div>
```

The technique of using an array's .forEach along with instanceof to spot the source of a TypeError, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000160/701302), comes in handy when catching the error.